# C# Excel COM plugin assembly bindingRedirect?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com, .net-assembly

I'm writing a Excel COM plugin with C# and .Net 4.8. The plugin use Utf8JsonReader from System.Text.Json package. This package need System.Memory as dependency, and Memory need System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe as dependency so Nuget install Unsafe package 4.0.6.0 for me. When come to run time, Excel successfully load my MyDll plugin, but Unsafe.dll not. .Net Framework didn't read MyDll.dll.config which contains bindingRedirect information, and used version 4.0.4.1 from Memory.dll's Manifest. According to exception's fusionLog, .Net find the dll file, but get a version mismatch error.

After some google, somebody says I need a EXCEL.exe.config near EXCEL.EXE, instead of MyDll.dll.config near MyDll.dll. It worked, but not a good solution for me, is there any good way to define bindingRedirect for dll plugin without "hack into Excel's installation"?

System.Memory.dll's Manifest:

[image: System.Memory.dll's Manifest]

Exception's fusionLog, not Unsafe Dll, but same problem:

[image: Exception's fusionLog]

Comment: Can you install 4.0.6.0 into the GAC?

Comment: @MiS Thanks! The main problem is, .Net never try to load 4.0.6.0, it's trying to load version 4.0.4.1 from disk, .Net just ignored rebind settings generate by VS. Infact 4.0.6.0's dll is just near MyDll.dll, if I build an EXE, every thing works fine. I add a fusionLog screenshot, hope helpful.

Comment: If you place the required version in the GAC, the Framework will look there first and should find and load it.

Comment: @MiS After some test, install dll to GAC doesn't work. You can read [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies). In my case, runtime determines a wrong version in first step "Determines the correct assembly version". I install the 4.0.6.0 to GAC, runtime just can't find it with a wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use an [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) event. Under this event you can try load a proper version of assembly which you need.

Comment: Thanks for answer. This event only fires when .Net fails to load an assembly. I can load missed assembly with this event. But if .Net load another version of assembly successfully, there is nothing I can do.